# LocalDeployer: app working directory

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an app that creates a file temporarily, does not delete it. I was hopping to see the contents of the file while running.

The app is deployed using the local deployer, does any body knows where would it create the file?? 
I tried the temp path, and also the working directory where the out and error logs are... nothing, the app does seem to be erroring, that would be on my normal console log.

Running on unix, temp is at /tmp.

thanks

Comment: Where your temp file lives likely depends on configuration.  And what operating system you're running.  Neither detail has been supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this location via the local deployer property `workingDirectoriesRoot` and `deleteFilesOnExit`.

For more information, you can refer this doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-deployer

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at the code of the local deployer, it seems the location it defaults to is the system temp path (System.getProperty(“java.io.tmpdir”)) and adds the stream id, plus the app id, etc. It is the same folder where the console and error streams write to.

thanks!